# Model score vs error function value

Tags: python, scikit-learn, model-evaluation, score-function

The model is trained with respect to custom error function.
For example:

```
estimators = [i for i in xrange(2000, 3000, 50)]
gammas = [0]#arange(0, 1.5, 0.3)
max_depths=[5]
scorer = mean_absolute_percentage_error
xgb_grid_params = dict(n_estimators = estimators, gamma = gammas, max_depth=max_depths)
xgb = XGBRegressor()
xgb_grid = GridSearchCV(xgb, xgb_grid_params, cv = 10, scoring=scorer, n_jobs = -1)
xgb_grid = trainGrid(xgb_grid, x, y, 'xgb', results)
```

Why model score differs from error function value? How can it be interpreted?

```
print xgb_grid.best_score_
0.535424141411

print mean_absolute_percentage_error(xgb_grid.best_estimator_, x, y)
0.027491551730793078
```

udp:

```
def mean_absolute_percentage_error(estimator, X, y):
    y_pred = estimator.predict(X)
    y_true = y
    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true))

def trainGrid(grid, x, y, name, results = None):
    directory = 'saved/' + name
    filename = 'saved/' + name + '/' + name +'.pkl'
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    try:
        grid = joblib.load(filename)
    except:
        print "saved model not found"
        print "started : ", str(datetime.datetime.now())
        start = time.time()
        print grid.fit(x, y)
        finish = time.time()
        print 'time : ', (finish - start)
        print "finished : ", str(datetime.datetime.now())
        joblib.dump(grid, filename)
    if (results is not None) and (not any(results.Algorithm == name)):
       results.loc[len(results)] = [name, grid.best_score_]

    return grid
```

Comment: Could you show your implementation of `trainGrid` and `mean_absolute_percentage_error`.

Comment: of course, i've updated the description